# Define specific column width for different rows in R

Tags: r, structure, rows

I am hardly new to R, but I can't find any solution for this. My target is to create a file wich is based on the "unknown" data type called "universal variable format" "*.uvf" and fill it's parameters from data of another file. The format is jused for different kind of (hydrological) time series.

The problem is, that it's header is a 4 row header type with a strong structure definition. I want to define each cell as a column.

A example: The third row in the header file should be constructed as this:

- Column 1-15: "Place"
- Column 16-25: "X coordinate "
- Column 26-35: "Y coordinate"
- and so on...

It is important, that the vector "X" got not more digits as 10 in column 16-25 in row 3. Otherwise the programm can't read the X coordinate.

I want to read the X coordinate from another file, save it as a vector called X and save it in the place explained above. After this the "real data" (e.g. precipitation) should listed under the header row by row for each day.

[The uvf Format (in german)](http://www.aquaplan.de/public_papers/imex/sectionUVF.html)

Example:

```
*Z
Abfluss        m3/s            K
A                 2509510   5636680       120
86110100158611010130
8611010015 0.184    
8611010030 0.189    
8611010045 0.191    
8611010100 0.1940000
8611010115 0.2010000
8611010130 0.2010000
```

There a few german entries; but that shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: Oh, lord, Hollerith cards again?  If there is any way you can rewrite or replace the "parent" code NOT to use fixed-length records, do so.  If you know your data file values are separated by [1,N] spaces, you'll be much happier using `scan` to load your data into R and then write to a file with your choice of delimiter.

Comment: Can you post some sample data? You can solve this (proabably) by using `read.fwf`.

Comment: The problem is, that the data wich I want to extract is not in the explained data structure. So read.fwf couldn't work in this case. Maybe sprintf() is a possibility; but I don't really know how to handle with this. But thanks so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Read in the first four lines using the readLines function and parse out the details you wnat from those four lines:

```
1. Zeile : *Z
2. Zeile : Spalte 1-15 Parameter, Spalte 16-30 Einheit, Spalte 32 DefArt (I,K,M)
3. Zeile : Spalte 1-15 Ort, Spalte 16-25 X, Spalte 26-35 Y, Spalte 36-45 Höhe
4. Zeile : Spalte 1-10 Start-Zeitpunkt, Spalte 11-20 End-Zeitpunkt
```

The second line could be parsed using either `read.fwf(textConnection(.))` on a single line or by using `substr`.

```
fmtlines <- readLines(textConnection("*Z
 Abfluss        m3/s            K
 A                 2509510   5636680       120
 86110100158611010130
 8611010015 0.184    
 8611010030 0.189    
 8611010045 0.191    
 8611010100 0.1940000
 8611010115 0.2010000
 8611010130 0.2010000
 Einheit<- substr( fmtlines[2], 16, 30 )
 Einheit
[1] "m3/s           "
```

Likewise then extract the rest of the parameters from lines three and four.

Step 2: You then use `read.fwf()` with the skip=4 parameter and the derived format parameters from the first step to complete the process.

Comment: Thank you! The readLines function with the text file works fine for me. With the "sub" function i'm able to replace the parameters for "fmtlines". Is it possible to set the number of strings for my new parameters? My new value for "Einheit" should have exactly 15 strings.

Comment: As far as I can tell the string length of Einheit was 15. The nchar() function is very helpful. I admit that I do remember having some difficulty finding it with the help system.